# How to create filters in a webpage like that of Flipkart and Amazon in java application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating a page dynamically which contains a list of hostel's in a particular area, I want tom implement a sidebar filter like that in Flipkart or amazon to refine my search result. How can this be done in java, can someone point me in the right direction.

My thoughts on this are : make a list of checkboxes with different categories and when a particular checkbox is selected, make a ajax call to the servlet which should fire a query with the desired results and display the result back on the page.

Comment: Do you need combobox type results?

Comment: Combobox ? I am not sure of it

Comment: @Ravinderz Did you got any solution

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are not interested in using lots of frameworks that do this for you (JSF + Richfaces or Primefaces etc, Spring MVC, Struts 2)

A possible-ugly solution would be:

1. Your Ajax calls your Servlet and all your work is done there (query etc)
2. You creates a html-list of components in your servlet (using a custom HtmlUtils to help you create tags and fill with data)
3. You send back to Ajax using below code

   ```
   (response is HttpServletResponse) from your doPost/doGet  
   response.setContentType("text/plain");  
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
   response.getWriter().write(data);
   ```
4. You get this data in Ajax like below and fills a Div content with your filtered result  (It uses jquery so you need import jquery javascript)

   ```
   $.ajax({  
       type: "GET",  
       url: servlet-url,  
       success: function(data){  
           $("#"+divid).html(data);  
       },  
       error: function(req, status, error){  
           //handle error here  
       }  
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wanted to try servlets and jsp before diving into frameworks to better understand the MVC flow. I will try this out.